# I want to Increase employee Id as E1,E2,E3 and so on how to do this

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to Increase employee Id as E1,E2,E3 and so on how to do this....Val(TextBox19.Text) + 1 I have done this to Increase 1,2,3 but how to append E at the start of every number in VB.net

Answer (score 0):

I made this by going all sneaky about it... 
But I think this is what you're looking for. With each click on the button, you get "E" + the incremented number.

Interested by the idea, I ended up on this for 5 hours :) (Nothing better to do)

```
Public Class Form1

'When Form1 loads.
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'We hide TextBox1
    TextBox1.Hide()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'This will increment +1 in the hidden textbox.
    Dim i As Integer

    i = Val(TextBox1.Text) + 1

    TextBox1.Text = i

    'We dim the result of the hidden textbox as string, then finally connect "Add" with "Result"
    Dim Add As String
    Add = "E"

    Dim Result As String
    Result = TextBox1.Text

    TextBox2.Text = Add & Result

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: :) I am Satisfied with ur Answer Sir But when 1 st Record Saved in database.. After Closing that form when I want to add new record... Textbox1.text will take 1 value from starting because it's value is not storing anywhere...

Comment: Then you'd need to read the database for their number, if it exists, move to next, until you get to a number that doesn't exist, and put that number as next inside a string. You will replace i with that number. Then create another "i" where it will increment that new number by 1. You asked the question, but you should've elaborated it. Because it makes big difference whether you save that number or not.